# Pass session variable from controller to view in express js

Tags: javascript, express, authorization

In express controller after log in to application using this code to redirect to main page:

```
 req.session.user = user.userLogin;
 if (req.session.user=='Admin') {
    global.loggedAdmin = user.userLogin;
 }
 else {
    global.loggedUser = user.userLogin;
 }   
 res.redirect('/');
```

And in main menu check if user is logged:

```
nav#menu.panel(role='navigation')
    ul
        li
        if loggedUser
            li
                span.setting Welcome #{loggedUser}
                    a(href='/account')
                        i.fa.fa-cog
            li
                hr
            li
                a(href='/logout') Logout
            li
        else if loggedAdmin
            li
                span.setting Welcome #{loggedAdmin}
                    a(href='/account')
                        i.fa.fa-cog
            li
                hr
            li
                a(href='/articles') Articles
            li
                hr
            li
                a(href='/files') Files
            li
                hr
            li
                a(href='/users') Users
            li
                hr
            li
                a(href='/logout') Logout
        else
            li
                a(href='/login') Log in
            li
                hr
            li
                a(href='/register') Register
```

And in app.js:

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'sdfghjkl2345678tyu',
    unset:'destroy',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
```

But when first log in as Admin and open website from another device menu catch user login as Admin. Can I pass session variable to pug template without using global in controller and if yes, how to do that?

Comment: Of course you can... how are you compiling / rendering the pug template? You can pass locals when doing either that get exposed to the template logic, rather than relying on global variables. Exposing critical flags like `isAdmin` to the global scope is extremely terrible practice and as you demonstrated, very insecure. Try to avoid using globals at all for your application logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First it is very important to use app.use() middleware before the app.router() middleware.

You can try this way in app middleware

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.myVar = 'sample value';
    next();
});
```

To get the value of myVar, in the jade file use

index.jade

```
extends layout
block content
    value of myVar is #{myVar}
```

voila!!!

But you might want too change the procedure, you are using right now. This is not a promising and secure way. Try to render the page with appropriate JSON value.